# Put an upper limit on the value of variable in R

Tags: r

How can I put an upper cap on the variable in R?

Suppose I have a data.frame with columns "a" and "b". Values of "b" range from 1:100. I want to make all values > 50 equal to 50.

I can write a loop and get this done, but I am in need of a function.

Answer (score 6):

As highlighted by @Frank, use the **parallel minima** function, `?pmin`

```
## example data
df <- data.frame(a = 1:100, b = 1:100)

df$b = pmin(df$b, 50)
```

`pmin` compares the input values and returns the minimum of them.

Comment: Or `df$b = pmin(df$b, 50)`

Comment: Thanks Frank. pmin() was the function I was looking for.

Comment: `df[df$b > 50, ]$b <- 50` looks very odd to me in that it subsets all of `df` first, then takes `b` from it - wouldn't `df$b[df$b > 50] <- 50` be more standard? Your second example in the commented out text seems appropriate too.

Comment: @thelatemail it's never struck me as odd, but that's not to say it isn't - I guess I've never really thought about it too much.

Comment: @Symbolix - try `df <- data.frame(b=30:70); df[df$b > 50, ]$b` for just one example of why it is a potentially bad idea. Also `seq(1:100)` is just `1:100`.

Comment: @thelatemail - I see. And certainly not a contrived example either. Thanks for the pointer.